# CMake with MinGW-w64 does not install built DLL, but it's being built fine

Tags: cmake, mingw-w64

**NB:** The files referenced here are all given below the horizontal ruler a bit down.

This is the MWE derived from a project where I ran into this. CMake version used is 3.12.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (16.04.6 to be precise).

The goal is to create a `CMakeLists.txt` which can be re-targeted to build a Windows DLL using the MinGW-w64 toolchain (`apt-get install mingw-w64` on Ubuntu/Debian).

When using no explicit toolchain file (i.e. without `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...`), all works as expected and the `lib${PRJNAME}.so` gets installed as desired. However, once I use the toolchain file given below, I only get the resulting import lib `${PRJNAME}Lib.dll.a` but not the corresponding `.dll` file installed.

If I invoke the Bash script as follows:

```
./build.sh 2>&1 |grep '^-- Install'
```

the output is:

```
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/user/cmake-test/build-native/install-target/lib/libtest.so
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/user/cmake-test/build-windows/install-target/lib/test.dll.a
```

As you can see the native build installs the *actual* shared library, but the one targeting Windows only installs the import lib, *not* the DLL. What I'd expect to see is something like this:

```
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/user/cmake-test/build-native/install-target/lib/libtest.so
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/user/cmake-test/build-windows/install-target/lib/test.dll
-- Installing: /home/user/cmake-test/build-windows/install-target/lib/test.dll.a
```

What is it I am doing wrong here? It would seem that the `install()` function is invoked properly:

```
install(
    TARGETS ${PRJNAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT library
)
```

Clearly `ARCHIVE DESTINATION` takes effect as that's where the import lib ends up. But why is the built `.dll` completely ignored here?

Side-note: I am aware of [`GNUInstallDirs`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), but that fell totally apart once I started cross-compiling for Windows. So I am setting the desired paths "manually" before invoking `install()`.

---

### build.sh (should be executable)

The script will first wipe the folders `build-native` and `build-windows`, if present, and then create those again. Then it will invoke `cmake` from these folders respectively, targeting using the system (native) toolchain and the MinGW-w64 toolchain respectively. Last but not least it will invoke the installation from these folders respectively.

So if you place this into an empty folder along with the other files this should not meddle with your data elsewhere in any way.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
for i in native windows; do
        D=build-$i
        test -d $D && rm -rf $D
        mkdir $D
        [[ "$i" == "windows" ]] && TCFILE=mingw64-64bit.cmake
        ( set -x; cd $D && cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. ${TCFILE+-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TCFILE} -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON )
        ( set -x; cd $D && cmake --build . --target install )
done
```

### test.cpp

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   if defined(test_EXPORTS)
#       define TEST_API  __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define TEST_API
#endif

TEST_API void SomeFunction()
{
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(PRJNAME test)
set(TARGET_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install-target")
project(${PRJNAME})

add_library(${PRJNAME} SHARED test.cpp)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    set(DLL_PREFIX)
    set(DLL_POSTFIX Lib)
else()
    set(DLL_PREFIX lib)
    set(DLL_POSTFIX)
endif()

set_target_properties(
    ${PRJNAME}
    PROPERTIES
    PREFIX "${DLL_PREFIX}"
    IMPORT_PREFIX "${DLL_PREFIX}"
    DEBUG_POSTFIX "${DLL_POSTFIX}"
    RELEASE_POSTFIX "${DLL_POSTFIX}"
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1
)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${TARGET_DIR})
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR lib)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR include)

install(
    TARGETS ${PRJNAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT library
)
```

### mingw64-64bit.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc-posix)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++-posix)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER  ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
install(
    TARGETS ${PRJNAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    COMPONENT library
)
```

According to the [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command documentation the DLL file is considered a runtime object.  I tested the example on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the issue. It's anything but obvious why one would be considered `RUNTIME` and the other `LIBRARY` ... oh well.

Comment: @0xC0000022L My only guess is because on Windows it's easy to place the DLL in the same location as the executable so that when running the executable it easily finds the DLL.